# nodeでform送信時に<textarea>内のname＝の値がUndefindと出力されてしまう

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

formタグ内のtextareaで入力した値をreq.body.～で受け取って表示しようとしてもUndefindと表示されてしまい困っています。
過去の[nodejsでのフォームの送信時にtextareaの値を取得する方法](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707555/how-to-get-value-of-textarea-on-submit-of-form-in-nodejs)を参考にし試しても表示できませんでした。
どうかご享受お願いします。
OS：Windows10

---

**server.js**

```
let express = require("express")
const mysql = require('mysql')
let app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}))
app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.post('/create', (req, res)=>{
    var title_db = req.body.zatuTitle
    var content_db = req.body.zatuarea
        connection.query('INSERT INTO zatu (title, content) VALUES ("' + title_db + '", ' + '"' + content_db + '")', 
            (error, results)=>{
              res.redirect('/')
            })
        })
```

**top.ejs**

```
<body>
    <form action="/create" method="POST">
            <input class="input" type="text" name="zatuTitle">
              <textarea class="textarea" name="zatuarea"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="button is-success is-rounded" value="投稿する">
    </form>
</body>
```

**package.json**

```
{

  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `req.body.zatuTitle`の値は取得できるけど、`req.body.zatuarea`は`Undefind`になるってことですよね？

Comment: はい、そうです。分かりにくくてすいません